# php full message show

Tags: php, mysql

After few word i put a read more button when i click read more it's show full message, it's Ok, but It's show all my post's full message. I need individual post's full message, Can you please tell me what is the wrong in my code bellow:
This is a function i used in my code in different file, name: "func.php"

```
<?php
function truncate($mytext,$link,$var,$id) {  
//Number of characters to show  
$chars = 200;  
$mytext = substr($mytext,0,$chars);  
$mytext = substr($mytext,0,strrpos($mytext,' '));  
$mytext = $mytext." <a href='$link?$var=$id'>read more...</a>";  
return $mytext;  
}  
?>
```

### This is index.php page code:

```
<?php
include "db/db.php";    
$upload_path = "secure/content/blogpostimg";
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY post_id DESC");
while ($rel = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$id = $rel['post_id'];
$sub = $rel['subject'];
$imgname = $rel['img_name'];
$img = $rel ['image'];
$msg = $rel['message'];
$date = $rel['date'];
$poster = $rel['poster'];
$cat_name = $rel['cat_name'];

echo "<h1>". "$sub" ."</h1>". "<br/>";
echo '<img src="' . $upload_path . '/' . $imgname . '" width="200"  />  ';
include_once("func.php");
echo truncate($rel['message'],"index.php","post_id",$rel['post_id']);  
}
?>
```

Comment: you are selecting all blog posts and looping through them, you need to use the post_id to select the specific post you want to view

Comment: this seems like repeating your previous question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493491/read-more-button-in-my-blog-with-php

Comment: because of it's no clear for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a check on `index.php` to see if the `$_GET['post_id']` is set, and if so, display a different MySQL select

```
if (isset($_GET['post_id']) && $_GET['post_id'] != '') {
    $p_id = (int) $_GET['post_id'];
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE post_id = '{$p_id}' ORDER BY post_id DESC");
} else {
    $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY post_id DESC");
}

// Your original code. Only at the end, if $p_id is set, display a full post view instead of the truncate() function
```

Comment: Hi, Indranil i used you code, instead of my select command but it's show full message of all my post.

Comment: I need individual post show the full message when i click show more button, but now it's show all my post's full message

Comment: Try this for the first `$sql` line:
`$sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog_post WHERE post_id = '{$p_id}' LIMIT 1");`
And also check if the correct `if` statement is getting triggered.

Comment: `echo substr($msg, 0, 200)."..." . "<a href=index.php?id=$id target='_blank'>Read more</a>";`

Change the link on this line to `index.php?post_id=$id` and try

Comment: Hello brother, same result. it's show full message of all my post. check index page of my update code.